# PEAR::Mail vs. PHP: Mail

Tags: email, pear, php, email-forwarding

I am creating a PHP system that will forward emails, (ie. someone@emailforprofession.com to someone@gmail.com) without using an SMTP server which is faster and more stable? PEAR::Mail or PHP: Mail? (or another one entirely)

I would be using extra headers and attachments but mainly trying to keep it looking and acting the same. (if anyone has an example for forwarding with attachments PLEASE provide it!)

And not exactly on the side but is there a way for people to be able to **send** email from they're someone@emailforprofession.com email address without having a complete inbox etc?

It would probably be better for me to use a real email provider but these are supposed to be free email addresses so paying by the email address is not an option, if anyone knows of a service that: charges by the month or year, has an API that email addresses can be created from and that can set up email forwards via the API that would be most appreciated.

I currently have a partial system together but would like to know which way I should go first.

Thank you all.

Comment: I'd go for option 3: Swift Mailer, http://swiftmailer.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The PEAR class supports multiple mailer backends, which allows you to
>   switch whenever needed and you'll be able to perform some benchmarks
>   and see which backend suits you best. The native mail function on the
>   other hand is much less advanced and will show a clear difference in
>   performance, especially for that amount of mails.
>
> I also suggest you have a look at PEAR's mail queue class:
>   http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue
>
> This is much more recommended for larger projects such as yours,
>   you'll also be able to implement a cron like feature which will send a
>   certain amount of mail per period you choose.

[Here](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/php-mail-vs-pear-mail-module-520896.html)

Comment: It would not be that much at first but could be later, this is already "running in the background", and would not be "while a user waits", basically if a user is not waiting, which one should I use?

Comment: The native mail function, `mail();` at first, but then if you're going major you can upgrade to PEAR's Mail.

Comment: Bluehost already has Pear so for now which should I create the script in?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea as to which I should use?